# GroupBy with Maximal Group Size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
column_a  ...
1         
1         
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
```

I now want to group the dataframe based on `column_a` but the resulting groups should be not of greater size than `s`.
So, for `s=2` the groups should be:
`(1,1), (1), (2), (3,3), (3,3), (3)`.

I have this working with a simple loop over the grouped dataframe (`df.groupby(['column_a'])`) and splitting the groups if they are too big but I have the feeling there is a shorter and more elegant way to do this.

Does anyone know a short and elegant method to group with a limited group size?

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please [edit] to add the tag for it. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you could group by `a` and the floor div of the groupby cumcount and s.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3]})
s = 2
df.groupby(['a',df.groupby('a').cumcount()//s]).size()
```

Output

```
a   
1  0    2
   1    1
2  0    1
3  0    2
   1    2
   2    1
```